# OpenCV - how many black objects are there in a photo?

Tags: c++, opencv

Okay, so I'm trying openCV with c++, and I want to do a simple detection program for objects that are black colored. So I have this simple code:

```
int main()
{
    Mat3b bgr = imread("C:/Users/sesoa/Desktop/photos/shapes.png");

    Mat3b hsv;
    cvtColor(bgr, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat1b mask1, mask2;
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), Scalar(180, 255, 30, 0), mask1);
    inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, 0, 0, 0), Scalar(180, 255, 40, 0), mask2);



    Mat1b mask = mask1 | mask2;

    imshow("Mask", mask);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

shapes.png is this:
[image]

all the shapes are rounded with color black. I would like for my program to tell me how many of connected black objects are there. Also the writing under the shapes is also black. So It shows me this as well, that's okay, cause this is a test photo anyway.

How can I modify my program to detect how many connected black objects are in the photo? (In this photo, the output should be "60" as there are 8 objects and 49 letters + 3 letters are 'i' so we have to count the dots).

EDIT:

I want the program to count black objects. I already get all black objects out like this:
[image]

Comment: Since you want pure black, why not try converting the image to gray scale and then find objects that are black?

Comment: @JeruLuke I already find black objects. I want to count how many of them are there. I'll edit...

Comment: find the number of contours present

Comment: You can try inverting the final image, then run findContours on it and count those contours whose size is greater than contours on letter (since you don't want those)

Comment: @RickM. I'm trying with cv::findContours right now. It doesn't bother me if I get letters, in fact it's better if I get the letters as well. What do you mean by inverting the final image?

Comment: By inverting I mean all white pixels to black and black to white. I tried it and it works perfectly with the findContours in counting the objects.

Comment: @RickM. ok, I inverted the image. Thanks for this. Thou I still can't get findContours to work..

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work?

Comment: @RickM. I don't understand how it works. I saw some sample code built like `findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );` but I don't understand what are those parameters...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143882/discussion-between-rick-m-and-user3029612).

Comment: Invert the image so that the objects are white and use connected components analysis. You'll have to be able to filter out the background, which you should be able to do by testing if the original color was white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of objects just do the following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours; 
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) ); // canny_output is the binary image
```

This will give you all the contours in the binary image (contours.size()). If you want only specific contours you can filter with contour area.

Hope it helps!